# pinescript 2 timeframe supertrend buy/sell

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to make super trend with 2 time frame. I use it on 2 min and use 5 min as higher time frame input in it. everything is good. I am stuck in adding condition to it. I want 2 min uptrend to plot when 5 min is in uptrend and same for opposite. 2 min downtrend to plot when 5 min is in downtrend.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Supertrend MTF Heikin Ashi', overlay=true)
HTF= input.timeframe('5', title='Time Frame')
Mult = input.float(defval=1.2, title='ATR Factor', minval=0.5, maxval=100,step=0.1)
Period = input.int(defval=5, title='ATR Period', minval=1, maxval=100)
//Heikin Ashi high, low, close
h = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period,high)
l = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period,low)
c = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period,close)
//HeikinAshi atr
Atr = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),timeframe.period, ta.atr(Period))
Up = (h + l) / 2 - Mult * Atr
Dn = (h + l) / 2 + Mult * Atr
float TUp = na
float TDown = na
Trend = 0
TUp := c[1] > TUp[1] ? math.max(Up, TUp[1]) : Up
TDown := c[1] < TDown[1] ? math.min(Dn, TDown[1]) : Dn
Trend := c > TDown[1] ? 1 : c < TUp[1] ? -1 : nz(Trend[1], 1)
Trailingsl = Trend == 1 ? TUp : TDown
linecolor = Trend == 1 and nz(Trend[1]) == 1 ? color.lime : Trend == -1 and nz(Trend[1]) == -1 ? color.red : na
// Higher Time Frame
highhtf = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), HTF,high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
lowhtf = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), HTF, low[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
closehtf = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), HTF, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
// ATR for HTF
HTfatr = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), HTF, ta.atr(Period)[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
Uphtf = math.abs(highhtf + lowhtf) / 2 - Mult * HTfatr
Dnhtf = math.abs(highhtf + lowhtf) / 2 + Mult * HTfatr
float TUphtf = na
float TDownhtf = na
TrendHtf = 0
TUphtf := closehtf[1] > TUphtf[1] ? math.max(Uphtf, TUphtf[1]) : Uphtf
TDownhtf := closehtf[1] < TDownhtf[1] ? math.min(Dnhtf, TDownhtf[1]) : Dnhtf
TrendHtf := closehtf > TDownhtf[1] ? 1 : closehtf < TUphtf[1] ? -1 : nz(TrendHtf[1], 1)
TrailingslHtf = TrendHtf == 1 ? TUphtf : TDownhtf
linecolorHtf = TrendHtf == 1 and nz(TrendHtf[1]) == 1 ? color.lime : TrendHtf == -1 and nz(TrendHtf[1]) == -1 ? color.red : na
plot(Trailingsl, color=linecolor, linewidth=2, title='SuperTrend')
plot(TrailingslHtf, color=linecolorHtf, linewidth=3, title='Supertrend HTF')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *linecolor* and *linecolorHtf* for reference
Something like that:

```
uptrend = Trend == 1 and nz(Trend[1]) == 1 and TrendHtf == 1 and nz(TrendHtf[1]) == 1
downtrend = Trend == -1 and nz(Trend[1]) == -1 and TrendHtf == -1 and nz(TrendHtf[1]) == -1
```